# jQuery selector to display the flowplayer tooltip over a td element

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, flowplayer

I'm trying to use the flowplayer tooltip tool (http://flowplayer.org/tools/demos/tooltip/table.html) to display a tooltip over a particular  element.

Here is my html:

```
<table id="menu-table" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" width="714" border="0" style="padding-top: 4px;">
 <tr>

  <td title="menu-one" style="background: url('images/menu-button.gif') top left no-repeat; text-align: center; vertical-align: middle; height:35px; width:115px; padding-right: 6px;">

   <a href="about.php">About</a>
   <div id="tooltip" class="tooltip">Tooltip text.</div>
  </td>
 </tr>
</table>
```

Note that the tooltip div part above is styled as display:none.

Here is the selector I'm trying to use...

```
$("#menu-table td[menu-one]").tooltip();
```

The tooltip() should display the hidden div, but I'm sure I have the selector wrong.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

try

```
$("#menu-table td[title='menu-one']").tooltip();
```

to select the TD with an argument title with value 'menu-one'

Comment: Hmm, that didn't seem to change anything offhand. -- but I'm also not 100% sure that it isn't an issue with the tooltip() function.  Is there a way to do a mouseover alert to see if the selector you provided is working?

Comment: Sure, just do $(...selector_above...).hover(function() { alert('hover'); });

Comment: I don't know the tooltip plug in but are you sure you don't have to select the actual DIV? with the above you're selecting the TD but not the hidden DIV

Comment: Should this:

$("#menu-table td[title='menu-one']").click(function(event){
     alert("Thanks for visiting!");
  });

Pop an alert?

Comment: Re: selecting the div -- not entirely sure, I think the tooltip() function displays the div though.

Comment: yes,  $("#menu-table td[title='menu-one']").click(function(event){ alert("Thanks for visiting!"); }); should show the alert on clicking the td...

Comment: Are you executing the selector inside a $(document).ready event? if you're not, may be that's the cause of your problem